# BerkeleyPacketFilter, filter by TCP and port

Tags: c#, tcp, port, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

**Filter by TCP and port, using the BerkeleyPacketFilter**

Having problem converting the code on tutorial from Pcap.net. Need to be able to filter packets by TCP and insert port value. I am not able to understand the BerkeleyPacketFilter syntax.

```
        //choose port
        Console.WriteLine("Choose port nr");
        string portnr = Console.ReadLine();
        int port = Int32.Parse(portnr);


        // Compile the filter
        using (BerkeleyPacketFilter filter = communicator.CreateFilter(port))
        {
            // Set the filter
            communicator.SetFilter(filter);
```

What is the syntax inside communicator.CreateFilter(how to insert the int port)):
I have also done the following:

```
       IpV4Datagram ip = packet.Ethernet.IpV4;
       TcpDatagram tcp = ip.Tcp;
```

this with the PcapDotNet.Packets.Transport.TransportDatagram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [the page in the Pcap.Net User Guide giving an example of how to use the BerkeleyPacketFilter class](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pcap.Net%20Tutorial%20-%20Filtering%20the%20traffic&referringTitle=Pcap.Net%20User%20Guide) is to be believed, the `CreateFilter` method does ***NOT*** take an integer as an argument, it takes a string as an argument.

This should not be surprising, given that [the documentation for the underlying libpcap/WinPCAP API for processing packet filters](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_compile.3pcap.html) shows that `pcap_compile()` takes a string as an argument, and that [the documentation for the format for filters](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html) indicates that a filter is a string.

If you want a string that matches a given TCP port number, the string is "tcp port *N*", where *N* is the port number.  You'd have to either take `port`, convert it to a string, and concatenate it with the string "tcp port " (complete with the blank after "port"), or just concatenate the `portnr` string with "tcp port ".

Note that you must also ***NEVER*** assume that `communicator.CreateFilter()` will succeed.  I don't see any on-line documentation for Pcap.Net, so I don't know whether the `CreateFilter` method will throw an exception for an invalid filter expression or not.

Comment: Thanks! Is there another way to go, instead of communicator.CreateFilter()? Another way of filtering with ip, tcp and port? in C#