# Berkeley Packet Filter to high level filtering expression

Tags: c#, c, winpcap, pcap.net, bpf

I have a C program which sets the filter for a WinPcap session manually by Berkeley Filter. Now I want to transfer this tool in C# with Pcap.Net. Pcap.Net doesn't offer the raw berkeley filter as argument but the high level filtering expression (also used in e.g. wireshark/tcpdump like `ip and tcp`)

Is there a way to

1. "Decompile" the Berkeley Packet Filter to an high level filtering expression
2. Use a raw byte stream for the filter in pcap.net

The raw bpf_program:

```
struct bpf_program bpf_program;
static struct bpf_insn bpf_insn [] =
{
    {
        BPF_LD + BPF_H + BPF_ABS,
        0,
        0,
        12
    },
    {
        BPF_JMP + BPF_JEQ + BPF_K,
        0,
        18,
        0
    },
    {
        BPF_LD + BPF_B + BPF_ABS,
        0,
        0,
        0
    },
    {
        BPF_JMP + BPF_JEQ + BPF_K,
        0,
        10,
        0
    },
    {
        BPF_LD + BPF_B + BPF_ABS,
        0,
        0,
        1
    },
    {
        BPF_JMP + BPF_JEQ + BPF_K,
        0,
        8,
        0
    },
    {
        BPF_LD + BPF_B + BPF_ABS,
        0,
        0,
        2
    },
    {
        BPF_JMP + BPF_JEQ + BPF_K,
        0,
        6,
        0
    },
    {
        BPF_LD + BPF_B + BPF_ABS,
        0,
        0,
        3
    },
    {
        BPF_JMP + BPF_JEQ + BPF_K,
        0,
        4,
        0
    },
    {
        BPF_LD + BPF_B + BPF_ABS,
        0,
        0,
        4
    },
    {
        BPF_JMP + BPF_JEQ + BPF_K,
        0,
        2,
        0
    },
    {
        BPF_LD + BPF_B + BPF_ABS,
        0,
        0,
        5
    },
    {
        BPF_JMP + BPF_JEQ + BPF_K,
        4,
        0,
        0
    },
    {
        BPF_LD + BPF_W + BPF_ABS,
        0,
        0,
        0
    },
    {
        BPF_JMP + BPF_JEQ + BPF_K,
        0,
        4,
        0xFFFFFFFF
    },
    {
        BPF_LD + BPF_H + BPF_ABS,
        0,
        0,
        4
    },
    {
        BPF_JMP + BPF_JEQ + BPF_K,
        0,
        2,
        0xFFFF
    },
    {
        BPF_LD + BPF_W + BPF_LEN,
        0,
        0,
        0
    },
    {
        BPF_RET + BPF_A,
        0,
        0,
        0
    },
    {
        BPF_RET + BPF_K,
        0,
        0,
        0
    }
};
bpf_program.bf_len = sizeof (bpf_insn)/sizeof (struct bpf_insn);
bpf_program.bf_insns = bpf_insn;
if (channel->type == ETH_P_802_2)
{
    bpf_insn [1].code = BPF_JMP + BPF_JGT + BPF_K;
    bpf_insn [1].jt = 18;
    bpf_insn [1].jf = 0;
    bpf_insn [1].k = ETHERMTU;
}
else
{
    bpf_insn [1].code = BPF_JMP + BPF_JEQ + BPF_K;
    bpf_insn [1].jt = 0;
    bpf_insn [1].jf = 18;
    bpf_insn [1].k = channel->type;
}
bpf_insn [3].k = channel->host [0];
bpf_insn [5].k = channel->host [1];
bpf_insn [7].k = channel->host [2];
bpf_insn [9].k = channel->host [3];
bpf_insn [11].k = channel->host [4];
bpf_insn [13].k = channel->host [5];
```

Edit to clarify: [Berkeley Packet Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Packet_Filter) is an interface for unix based system. WinPcap uses this BPF and so does Pcap.Net. Pcap.Net has a class to handle the BPF which is also called `BarkeleyPacketFilter`. The Class only accepts high level filtering expression (like `tcp port 80`).

I search for a way to feed the BPF-Class with the raw filter (see code block above) not with the high level expression.

Comment: what is a `raw berkeley filter`?
does that link help? https://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pcap.Net%20Tutorial%20-%20Filtering%20the%20traffic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BerkeleyPacketFilter, filter by TCP and port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675476/berkeleypacketfilter-filter-by-tcp-and-port)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `BerkeleyPacketFilter` objects of Pcap.Net are [simple wrappers around a reference to the `bpf_program` structure](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/blob/00db65c8ba6c6a5f0239da7b1b9a057bfadeb314/PcapDotNet/src/PcapDotNet.Core/BerkeleyPacketFilter.h#L84).

It's clearly a hack, but you can probably replace the private field of those objects using `System.Reflection`:

```
using (BerkeleyPacketFilter filter = communicator.CreateFilter("ip and tcp"))
{
    var prop = filter.GetType().GetField("_bpf",
                                         System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic
                                         | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
    prop.SetValue(filter, &your_bpf_program);

    communicator.SetFilter(filter);
}
```